# Nikon P510, Is it possible to shoot an image while charging?

Tags: nikon, timelapse, charger

I'd like to make few time lapse videos but unfortunately discovered that my Nikon P510 refuses to turn on while connected to the charger. Is it possible to work around this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.imaging-resource.com/PRODS/nikon_p510/nikon_p510A.HTM):

> You charge the battery in the camera using a small square adapter with a folding plug that connects to the included USB cable. That means you can charge the battery from your laptop's USB port, but it also means you can't shoot while your battery is charging. You have to charge it in the camera.

Comment: But maybe there's a way to run it not with a battery, but using a cable?